# Where can I find google geocode alternatives?

Tags: xml, json, web, geolocation

I know this link:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=51,-93

which helps me finding data (especially the postal code which I want to know) of a specific place when I know the lattitude and longitude values of that place.

Since googleapis is just one option and it may be geographically restricted content, I am looking for alternatives, hopefully with a similar level of simplicity, that can be used to determine the postal code (in xml or json) when the longitude and lattitude are known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled it, and got 2 pretty nice alternatives.

[Bing Maps Location Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx)

And

[Yahoo PlaceFinder](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/requests-pf.html)

Comment: Thanks. The yahoo placefinder does not seem to accept longitude and lattitude as input  (does it? Examples contain street names). Correct me if am wrong. The bing maps api may be a good option: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx because of a concrete example http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/47.64054,-122.12934?o=xml&key=BingMapsKey . I think I am going to get a bing maps key.

Comment: Actually it does accept coordinates, [free-form-format](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/address-formats.html#free-form-format).